# How to measure a mean frequence of fft transform

Tags: time-series, matlab, frequency, fourier-transform, harmonic-mean

I have this time series (utilization of app by day of an user)
[image]

And this fourier transform of the above time series
[image: fft of a time series]

**How can I extract one number that express the mean frequency of this time series?**

**It would be related to the weighted mean, or the harmonic mean somehow?**